# Query a specific child node in all instances of a parent node in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to figure out how, if possible, to query a specifically named child node in all instances of a parent node in Firebase. It can be assumed that all parent nodes queried have this specifically named child node in it.

In this example, `uid` is a unique identifier for each user and I'm trying to get a list of `displayNames`:

```
{
  users: {
    uid: {
      displayName: "stringOfSomeKind"
    }
    uid2: {
      displayName: "moreStrings"
    }
    uid3: {
      displayName: "evenMoreStrings"
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

The purpose of this is so I can check to see if a `displayName` is currently taken. (I can't use the `displayName` as the primary key because when a user logs in, I'll only have the `uid` available.)

How can I efficiently check to see if one of these `displayNames` is already taken? Do I have to denormalize my data to do so efficiently? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a node from Firebase, you also get all data under that node. Assuming that you have more data per user than just their display name, that can indeed lead to needlessly loaded data.

If you only want to load a list of display names, you should indeed store a list of display names.

```
{
  displayNames: {
    "stringOfSomeKind": "uid",
    "moreStrings": "uid2",
    "evenMoreStrings": "uid3"
  }
}
```

If you come from a background of relational/SQL databases, this may seem unnatural at first. For me it helped to realize that these structures are indexes, same as the "index by displayName" that you might add to your relational database. The difference is that in NoSQL/Firebase it is your code that maintains the index, while in most RDBMSs such indexes are maintained by the system.

Comment: Yeah, I'm more used to relational databases. I saw this structure somewhere else and I was confused somewhat—your answer makes complete sense though. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

> Firebase world is quite different!

When such scenarios come you have to think to redesign your database structure, In your case uid is unique identifier so is displayName- speaking technically.

You will have to maintain additional data like:

```
{
  users: {
    uid: {
      displayName: "stringOfSomeKind"
    }
    uid2: {
      displayName: "moreStrings"
    }
    uid3: {
      displayName: "evenMoreStrings"
    }
    ... 
  }
 displayNames: {
        "display_name": "uid",
        "display_name2": "uid2",
        "display_name3": "uid3"
     ...      
 }
}
```

Happy Helping!

Comment: What are the pros and cons of doing a .indexOn displayName instead of denormalizing something as simple as this?  Which approach would be better?